# Help on linear differential equation problem

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations

Consider the linear, inhomogeneous system $\frac{d\hat{w}}{dt}=A\hat{w}+\hat{b}$, where $A$ is a constant 3x3 matrix, $\hat{w}= \begin{bmatrix}
x(t) \\
y(t) \\
z(t)
\end{bmatrix}$, and $\hat{b}= \begin{bmatrix}
-2+e^{9t} \\
e^{9t} \\
1+e^{9t}
\end{bmatrix}$.
 Suppose that
\begin{equation}
W(t) =                                                                                                                                                                    
\begin{bmatrix}                                                                                                                                                                  
-2e^{2t} & 0 & e^{6t} \\                                                                                                                                                                    
0 & 2e^{2t} & e^{6t} \\                                                                                                                                                                     
e^{2t} & 2e^{2t} & e^{6t}                                                                                                                                                                        
\end{bmatrix}  
\end{equation}

is a fundamental matrix for the corresponding linear homogenous system. Note that this problem involves only simple computations.

a) What are the eigenvalues and eigenspace of $A$? Is $A$ diagonalizeable?

b) Find a particular solution $\hat{w}_p(t)$ to the above inhomogenous system and verify that it is indeed a solution. Note that you do not need to find $A $ explicitly to carry out this verification.

c) Find another solution to the inhomogenous system that satisfies $x(0) = \frac{1}{3}$, $y(0) = 3+\frac{1}{3}$, and $z(0) = 4- \frac{1}{2}+ \frac{1}{3}$.

d) If you subtract your solution in part (c) from your solution in part (b), what first order system does this difference solve?

Any help would be much appreciated :)

Comment: Are you able to make progress?

Answer (score 1):

**Hints**

$(a)$ We can read the eigenvalues and eigenvectors directly from the the given Fundamental Matrix. Why is this diagonalizable?

**Note:** We can also find $A$ explicitly, although it shouldn't be needed as $A = W'(t)~ W^{-1}(t)$.

$(b)$ We can write the solution as

$$\hat w_p(t) = W(t)~W(t_0)~X_0 + \int_{t_0}^t W(t)~ W^{-1}(s)~\hat{b}(s)~ds$$

Calculate the given expression and then substitute it back into the system and verify it solves it.

$(c)$ The previous formula is quite useful.

$(d)$ Perform the subtraction and then answer.